# How can I write the contents of AbstrDoubleList into TextArea?

Tags: java, list, abstract

I have a little problem when I am trying write contents of AbstrDoubleList into TextArea.

I have class  AutoPujcovna.class

```
public class AutoPujcovna implements IAutoPujcovna {

   public AbstrDoubleList<IAuto> listVypujcenychAut = new AbstrDoubleList();
   public AbstrDoubleList<IPobocka> listPobocek = new AbstrDoubleList();

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "Seznam poboček: \n " + this.listPobocek;
}

@Override
public void vlozPobocku(IPobocka paramIPobocka, EnumPozice paramEnumPozice)    {
    switch (paramEnumPozice) {
        case PRVNI:
            listPobocek.vlozPrvni(paramIPobocka);
            break;
        case PREDCHUDCE:
            listPobocek.vlozPredchudce(paramIPobocka);
            break;
        case NASLEDNIK:
            listPobocek.vlozNaslednika(paramIPobocka);
            break;
        case POSLEDNI:
            listPobocek.vlozPosledni(paramIPobocka);
            break;

    }
}
.
.
.
```

than I have GUI with button and this button is calling

```
autopujcovna.vlozPobocku("Enterprise", EnumPozice.PRVNI);
textArea.append(autopujcovna.toString());
```

but when I am trying read the DoubleList I get only

```
"Pobočky: classes.AutoPujcovna@10d47c7"
```

Don't you know where can be mistake?

UPDATE:

When I am trying add a new Pobocka to combobox
      `jComboBox3.addItem(autopujcovna.zpristupniPobocku(EnumPozice.AKTUALNI).toString());` everything is working and I see all what I need, but still I can't see that in TextArea

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `toString()` in `AbstrDoubleList` and `IPobocka`

```
public AbstrDoubleList<IPobocka> listPobocek = new AbstrDoubleList();
```

Or define getter/setter and access using that specifically.

Comment: I already added, but nothing change. When I am trying add it to combo box so I am getting toString from Pobočka. In combo box its working but not in textarea :/

Comment: Can you please update your question to current behaviour. I didnt get much from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I just used for cycle :)

```
for (Iterator<IPobocka> it = this.autopujcovna.iterator(eTyp.POBOCKY); it.hasNext();) {
            IPobocka ipb = (IPobocka) it.next();
            this.textPobocky.append(ipb + "\n");
        }
```